# BigQuery Java API Convert Row to Java Object

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I am using [this library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) to interact with BigQuery API. Is there a way to convert the returned rows into a Java Object easily? Or do I have to work with the `Schema` and `FieldValueList`?

Comment: They are Java objects e.g. https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/com/google/cloud/bigquery/FieldValueList.html. Those are the objects you need to work with for this lib/SDK.

Comment: If you are using the Java BigQuery client (which is recommended), you would need to work with the `Schema` and `FieldValueList`. They are manual written abstractions sitting on top of the [discovery-based Java BigQuery API](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/tree/master/clients/google-api-services-bigquery/v2).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you are using the Java BigQuery client (which is recommended), you would need to work with the Schema and FieldValueList since they are part of the manually written layer on top of the BigQuery API. You could iterate on the object and maybe construct a new object:

```
for (FieldValueList values : result.iterateAll()) {
      for (FieldValue value : values) {
        for (FieldValue record : value.getRecordValue()) {
          // construct new object
      }
}
```

If you wish to not use Schema and FieldValueList, you can use the [auto-generated BigQuery Java client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/tree/master/clients/google-api-services-bigquery/v2).

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you want to parse it to list of map

```
List<Map<String, Object>> bqResult = new ArrayList<>();
Schema schema = result.getSchema();
for (FieldValueList row : result.iterateAll()) {
    Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>();
    for(Field field : schema.getFields()){
       m.put(field.getName(), row.get(field.getName()).getStringValue());
    }
    bqResult.add(m);
}
```