# Spring boot integration with bigquery

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-bigquery, spring-cloud-gcp-bigquery

I would like to know if it is possible to map a big query table to a java class like we do for mongo with @document annotation.
I am unable to find one.
pom file snippet-

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-bigquery</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61548938/3122175

Comment: Thanks!!. how would i  insert a pojo object into BQ